# How do I create an export batch script in Illustrator CS4?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I create a batch script that would export a set of AI files in CS4 to a png of a certain size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a scripts folder somewhere like this: `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS2\Presets\Scripts`.  Copy the `ExportDocsAsFlash.js` to `ExportDocsAsPNG24.js` and modify using the [AI Javascript Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/pdfs/AICS2-JavaScriptGuide.pdf) as a guide.

I tried this w/ CS2 (code below), but there seems to be a bug in the engine.  For PNG's (and GIF's it seems) it doesn't access subsequent document objects so it saves the same document each time.  Hopefully CS4 has this patched.

```
var j, sourceDoc, targetFile;

var destFolder = null;
// Get the destination to save the files
destFolder = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select the folder where you want to save the exported files.', '~' );

if (destFolder != null) {
  for ( j = 0; j < app.documents.length; j++ ) {
    sourceDoc = app.documents[ j ]; // returns the document object

    targetFile = getNewName(sourceDoc, destFolder);

    // set PNG export options
    var opt = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    opt.antiAliasing = true;
    opt.transparency = true;

    // Export
    sourceDoc.exportFile(targetFile, ExportType.PNG24, opt);
  }
  alert( 'Files are saved as PNG24 in ' + destFolder );
}

function getNewName(sourceDoc, destFolder) {
  var docName = sourceDoc.name;
  var ext = '.png'; // new extension for png file
  var newName = "";

  // if name has no dot (and hence no extension,
  // just append the extension
  if (docName.indexOf('.') < 0) {
    newName = docName + ext;
  } else {
    var dot = docName.lastIndexOf('.');
    newName += docName.substring(0, dot);
    newName += ext;
  }

  // Create a file object to save the png
  saveInFile = new File( destFolder + '/' + newName );
  return saveInFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with inkscape's export option.

First install inkscape:

```
apt-get install inkscape
```

Create an `export_to_png.sh` script with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls $1);
do
        inkscape -w100 -h100 -e $1/$i.png $1/$i
done
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x export_to_png.sh
```

Then run it:

```
./export_to_png.sh /path/to/images/
```

It will convert "somefile.ai" to "somefile.ai.png" with 100x100 size.