# How to change the artboard size in Illustrator via batch script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I worked over 80 hours on a school project, the last step was animating in AE, but because of a small problem everything looks jagged.

I have around 6000 PDF's, and the solution would be to make the artboard size around 6 times bigger. However, Illustator's actions don't include artboard changes.

I found this script from hyperslug:

> [How do I create an export batch script in Illustrator CS4?](https://superuser.com/questions/100111/how-do-i-create-an-export-batch-script-in-illustrator-cs4)

Is it possible to accomplish this?

(I have access to CS4 and CS5)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted this too, and found a JavaScript by Carlos Canto (posted 5/4/11) on Adobe's forum:

> http://forums.adobe.com/message/3655752

If you can't create a script from the post, let me know. I've saved Carlos' code as a script, and made a duplicate script which does not ask for padding; it simply snaps the new artboard to the content.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

http://herkulano.github.com/illustrator-scripts-for-mobile/

An Illustrator script to help you in the mobile world

I created this Adobe Illustrator Script to help me export PNGs from layers for different densities (iOS Retina Display, Android Devices, etc).

The script asks for 3 values in sequence:

The folder where you want to save the files.

The scale factor 1 = 100% = 160dpi = mdpi, 2 = 200% = 320dpi = retina display (these values are only valid if you designed for 160dpi aka mdpi).

A suffix if you want to use one, e.g., @2x for retina display in iOS. You can also leave it empty if you don’t want a suffix or if you are exporting to android or iOS non-retina.
Locked layers visibility will be ignored and also they will not be exported.

For example, this can be used to keep global layers visibility or guide layers from being exported.